# Clients can't see new records

Tags: java, mysql, percona

i have a problem when run tow clients of my java application on the network, first client insert a record second client can see it when refreshing the resultset, now when 2nd client insert a new record the first client can't see that record even after refreshing, when the first client close the application and re run it, record from the 2nd client show normally !!!!! so what happened ? how can i monitor both of them to trace my problem ? Note: when setting AutoCommit true after COMMIT, every thing just work fine. do i need any extra configuration on my.cnf ??

Comment: maybe the `List<Data>` that you get is not re-assigned with the new values and it works the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first client never commits its transaction, even though it only reads (select) it keeps the connection and the transaction open, and hence it will be in an "old transactional-state" when refreshing. Make sure client one gets a new resultset (don't just refresh it) or even simpler - just set AutoCommit to true which you state works.

Edit:Took away my first answer which I now think it wrong. (I said 2nd client didn't commit, I missread the question somewhat.)

Comment: they run the same application, the application for any insert or update have the scenario (initAutoCommit set to false, do insert or update, finally commit). that what make me confused.

Comment: Hm, do you mean you iterally run two instances of the same application? (Don't think that is relevant, but can't be sure.) Try closing the connection between each read/write in both applications, to see if that fixes your problem (it is not a good fix, but help track down the problem). Of course best thing would be to provide us with a lot more info including code. (As a side point, why don't you just use autocommit?)

Comment: I have used your idea (Connect when need db then closing it after select, update, delete, insert) that work 100% but as you said it's not good idea, i like to connect when lunch the application and keep one connection only (Connect, close, reconnect not a good idea) i do the connection when application run and keep it for all the work until user close the application. autocommit will be bad idea for my application since it an ERP for hospitals & working on network ACID is a priority here.

Comment: Well yeah, (changed my answer since it is client 1 that isn't commiting when it should). So don't use autocommit then, but look closely at how client 1 "refreshes". It is true you should use the same connection for a long time. But commiting is maybe the most important part of ACID. "Client one reads stale data" - agree?

Comment: if you have a "team viewer 7" i can show you a live screen for what i want exactly. ID: 697 146 985 Pass: 5799, i will change it after 15 minutes to prevent other from connecting to my computer, can you?

Comment: No, don't use nor want. sorry.

Comment: OK, i tried to use setAutoCommit(true); after using commit(); it's worked but is this will affect the transaction criteria? taking on consed ration that i will keep setAutoCommit(false); in each time i start a new transaction.

Comment: when i started a transaction i have set conn.setAutoCommit(false); then after transaction done i did commit(); i have checked the status of autoCommit mode after commit i found that autoCommit mode still false !!!!!

what is wrong ?

Comment: Next to last comment: Don't know what you mean with "transaction criteria". Last comment: Nothing is wrong, you set autoCommit to false, which means you have to commit "manually" of course autoCommit is gonna be false after you've commited, since you set it to false. Transactions and ACID environment is complex (in a lot of circumstances very to absurdly complex) - there is a lot to learn and think about, at least your on your way to understanding why you had a problem in the first case here. But it really takes years for most coders to "master" this.